# Typescript 3.5.1 "incompatible types" error in old code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've some old code like this

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
type Foo = string | object | JQuery;

let x: Foo = { bar: 33}; // just a generic object
let y: Foo = { stop: 33}; // meant to a generic object, but...
```

With Typescript 3.5.1 I get this error for `y`.

> Types of property `stop` are incompatible. Type `number` is not
>   assignable to type `{ (queue: string, clearQueue?: boolean,
>   jumpToEnd?: boolean): JQuery<HTMLElement>; (clearQueue?: boolean,
>   jumpToEnd?: boolean): JQuery<HTMLElement>; }`.

Obviously it's inferring (incorrectly) that `{stop:33}` is meant to be a `JQuery`?

Is this a compiler bug?
If not, how to avoid the problem?

---

To explain why `Foo` is defined that way... It's used as a parameter type to functions, allowing the conversion of Foo to an XML string, like this. Depending on the type of Foo it's treated as an existing XML string, a DOM node, or a generic object which is translated to xml.

```
private paramToString(data: Foo): string {
  let result = isJquery(data) ? new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data[0]) :
    (typeof data === "string" ? data : new XML2JS.Builder().buildObject(data));
  return result;
  }
```

Comment: If it's meant to be a generic object, why declare it with type `Foo`? I'm having trouble seeing what `Foo` is for. I get `string | JQuery`, but `object`?

Comment: Change the key name  instead of `stop` and try. Because may be some `stop()` functions are there with the same name in inside of `JQuery` object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see my edit. Ramesh: Yes, that's what's happening, but changing the key name isn't an option for me here.

Comment: Try doing `type Foo = string | object;`

Comment: Probably casting it explicitly would get rid of the error?

Comment: Try: `type Foo = string | object | JQuery | {stop: any};`

Answer (score 2):

Yup, looks like JQuery type has `stop` defined and it's not a number. The simplest solution is to explicitly tell that your value is a simple object.

```
let y: Foo = {stop: 33} as object;
```